# Firebase function is called, but func method .set() after .doc() is not working

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I m trying to create a document in Firebase Firestore via Firebase Function calling from client (Android).

As documentation says we could create a reference on the future doc and set info some lines later: 
[firebase github](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/40b8cb96f4b27907d9094b604a0e4bd607beadb7/firestore/main/index.js#L225-L230)

I get the doc ID on my client but the doc is not added to the Firestore, so "set()" is not working.

What could be wrong?

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

export const createPack = functions.https.onCall((data) => {

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
console.log("[CREATE PACK] START");

const db = admin.firestore();
var document = db.collection("packs").doc();

console.log("[CREATE PACK] GOT REF");

document.set({
    title: data.title,
    date: data.date,
    total: data.total,
    activated: 0
});

let packId = document.id;

console.log('[CREATE PACK] PACK ID ' + packId);
console.log('[CREATE PACK] END');

return {
    "id": packId
};
```

});

I expect adding data to Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


export const createPack = functions.https.onCall((data) => {

    console.log("[CREATE PACK] START");

    const db = admin.firestore();

    var documentRef = db.collection("packs").doc();

    console.log("[CREATE PACK] GOT REF");

    return documentRef.set({
        title: data.title,
        date: data.date,
        total: data.total,
        activated: 0
    })
    .then(() => {
        const packId = documentRef .id;

        console.log('[CREATE PACK] PACK ID ' + packId);
        console.log('[CREATE PACK] END');
        return { "id": packId };
    });

});
```

You have to return a promise after an asynchronous operation, see the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable. (I would also suggest you watch the 3 videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/)

Also, note that since Cloud Functions version 1.0  "you can no longer pass in `functions.config().firebase` when initializing". See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin. Finally note that you have to initialize outside of the Cloud Function itself.